# How to terminate a python process and enter the finally block in python try-except statement?

Tags: python, operating-system, try-catch, terminate

I have two python files: `script.py` and `counting.py`.

*counting.py*

```
from time import sleep

try:
    for n in range(1, 10):
        print('counting', n)
        sleep(1)
except Exception as e:
    print('program terminated with exception', e)
else:
    print('program ended')
finally:
    sleep(4)
    print('this is the finally block')
```

*script.py*

```
import sys
import pathlib
import subprocess
import signal


on_windows = True if sys.platform == 'win32' else False
on_linux = True if sys.platform == 'linux' else False

if on_windows:
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['python', 'counting.py'],
        cwd=pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
    )
elif on_linux:
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ['python', 'counting.py'],
        cwd=pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True,
        preexec_fn=os.setsid,
    )
try:
    out, err = process.communicate(timeout=4)
    print(out, err)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    if on_windows:
        process.send_signal(signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
        process.kill()
    elif on_linux:
        os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    print('time out')
```

When I run `script.py` the output is:

```
time out

Process returned 0 (0x0)        execution time : 4.778 s
```

**How can I terminate the `process`, and enter the `finally` block in the `counting.py` file?**

*P.S.
When I run `counting.py` in the terminal, the program enters the `finally` block, after a `CTRL+C` on the keyboard:*

```
>>python counting.py
counting 1
counting 2
counting 3
this is the finally block
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "counting.py", line 6, in <module>
    sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
>>
```

How can I achieve this using the `subprocess` module and killing the child process?
I have tested the above codes in Windows (Windows 10) and Linux (CentOS 8).

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but `break` keyword will stop your loop. Just enter it in a blank line.

Comment: `True if x else False` is just `bool(x)` (which is itself sometimes just `x`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `counting.py` won't print anything unless you let it emit something to stdout:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python', 'counting.py'],
    cwd=pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(),
    stdout=None,
    stderr=None,
    universal_newlines=True,
    preexec_fn=os.setsid,
)
```

Second, your exception handler in `script.py` doesn't get called, because it's not a timeout exception, so change to:

```
try:
    out, err = process.communicate(timeout=4)
    print(out, err)
except:
```

Third, at least on Linux, `os.killpg()` will terminate the process rather than interrupt it, so the exception handler in `counting.py` wouldn't be called. Instead of `SIGTERM`, use:

```
elif on_linux:
    os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGINT)
```

With those 2 changes:

```
$ ./script.py 
counting 1
counting 2
time out
$ this is the finally block
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "counting.py", line 8, in <module>
    sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```